# Make Conversation in a Yammer feed private

Tags: team-sites, yammer

Usualy you can use following code to embed Yammer feed on a SharePoint Team or Project site. The problem is you have to create a private Yammer group for the Team site and connect your feed to that yammer group, if you want to make your yammer conversation on the site private. Otherwise all conversation of the members of the Team site will be visible on the yammer portal. So you need to create a Private Yammer group for each Team or Project site. If you have 100 project sites you need to have 100 Private Yammer Groups.

Is there a way to make your conversation on a Yammer Feed completly private without creating a Yammer Group?

```
yam.getLoginStatus(function (response){
  if(!response.authResponse){
     yam.connect.embedFeed({
       container:"#embedded-feed",
       network: "myNetWork",
       feedType: sFeedType,
       feedId: sFeedId
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set security on a thread in Yammer, only on Groups. So yes, if you want to enable security on a per-team basis you'll need to set up a group for each team.

Also, watch out when using the Yammer embed in a secured context. Users can post to any group they choose, and you can't fix that, so they need to be aware of that.